# Cannot get variable out of loop

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to build shell command in with bahs loop from a file.

I have file with contents like this:

```
artist="artist"
title="title"
composer=""
```

and loop like this:

```
grep -v '=""' "$dir/input.file" | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
    tag+="-metadata ${line} ";
    echo $tag;
done    
echo "ffmpeg -n -i "$dir/$file" -loglevel error -map_metadata 0 $tag";
```

while in a loop it works fine:

```
-metadata artist="artist"
-metadata artist="artist" -metadata title="title"
```

however final output does not contain what was build in loop

```
ffmpeg -n -i /somepath -loglevel error -map_metadata 0
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why variable values are lost after terminating the loop in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144029/why-variable-values-are-lost-after-terminating-the-loop-in-bash). Short solution: Use `shopt -s lastpipe; grep ... | while ...` or `while read ... done < <(grep ...)`.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: thanks redid my loop like this:
while read line;
do
 tag+="-metadata ${line} ";
 echo $tag;
done << $(grep -v '=""' "$dir/$file")

echo "ffmpeg -n -i "$dir/$file" -loglevel error -map_metadata 0 $tag";

and now i get this result:
-metadata
-metadata -metadata echo "ffmpeg -n -i "/somepath/" -loglevel error -map_metadata 0";